# SAP Business Intelligence table by table

Tags: crystal-reports, business-intelligence, business-objects, rich-client-platform

I am using the Web Intelligence Rich Client, if I want to do something like

```
ID: XXXX

Name: Name1

Department: Dept1
```

```
ID: YYYY

Name: Name2

Department: Dept2
```

```
ID: ZZZZ

Name: Name3

Department: Dept3
```

So on, so on......

Is there a table format in Rich Client that allow me to do this? Or it's better to do it using Crystal report? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Rich client or web client of Web Intelligence shouldn't matter.

First turn your table into a **Horizontal Table** by right-clicking on the table and choosing **Turn Into > Horizontal Table** from the context menu.

Then set your lowest level object as section by right-clicking on that object and choosing **Set as section** from the context menu. I used **Store name** from the e-Fashion universe. You may want to use **Department** in your case. That will move whatever object you set as the section out of your table to be the section header like this...

[image]

Next hide that section header and add it back to your table to get your desired result.

[image]